# Trying to toggle a boolean variable with a button

Tags: javascript, html, variables, if-statement, atom-editor

I am trying to toggle a variable with a button. The code doesn't toggle, it only outputs what the variable initially was.

```
<button id="lock" onclick="togle()">
<img id="img1" src="images/lock.png" class="center">

<script>

var mode = false;

function togle() {
    if (mode == true) {
        mode = false;
    } else {
        mode = true;
    }
}

</script>
```

The result is always the default variable.

The variable should toggle between `true` and `false`, but it just stays constant.

Comment: do you have the same problem if you use `===` instead of `==` for the if condition?

Comment: also, do you have a closing tag for the button element? `</button>`

Comment: yes === doesnt help and yes <button> has a closing tag sorry for croping it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue after fixing the `html` markup, i.e, adding a closing tag to the button (`</button>`). However, to toggle between `false` and `true` you can just do `mode = !mode` inside the `toggle()` method:

```js
var mode = false;

function toggle()
{
    mode = !mode;
    console.log("mode is: " +  mode);
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<button id="lock" onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: @viktornikolov Could you made a working example that reproduce the issue. Also, add a log inside `toggle` function to be sure it is called every time you click the button.

Comment: well that fixed it
thaks friend i have been struggling with this for way to long